# Buying memory / What are the blue vs black spots

Tags: memory, upgrade

The last time I installed ram myself they were little green circuit boards.

I have identified my mother board as MSI P67A-G45 [seen here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P67AG45_B3/Gallery)

I am using two slots and I want to put in an 8GB kit (2x4GB) upgrade

From this [badly taken picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX2Y5.jpg) with the case still on I can see the two blue spots are taken up, and at least one of the black spots is not.  I assume the other black spot is empty.

My Questions are:

- what does the blue and black signify?  When I get two more sticks will I have to buy a casing or will they come with a casing?
- does the memory need to stay in pairs, and if so are the two blue spots consider the pair or one blue/black make a pair?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual for the motherboard:

[image: It's a manual. How exciting!]

Comment: Thank you... should have read the manual.  I am still concerned about this blue casing, will the other two need a similar casing and where would I get such a thing.

Comment: It's a heat sink. If the memory needs it then it will come with.

Comment: To elaborate, the coloring designates memory pairs.  If you have dual channel memory, then it will (generally) use the dual channel method when paired memory is installed in these slots.  Paired memory means memory of the same specs (bus speed, size, manufacturer, latency, etc.).  If you don't pair the memory (using different GB sizes of DIMMS or putting them in different colors slots), the coloring doesn't matter.  Reminder: stay under the max GB your mobo can recognize.

Answer (score 1):

The blue cover is the heat spreaders/heat sink.

You can install any brand even without the heat spreaders as long as the specs are compatible memory.

Refer this link for compatible memory spec: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/MicrostarIntP67AG45B3Mainboard.html